# Drawing points with GL_POINTS and GL_POINT_SMOOTH results it two pixel tall points?

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

I have the following:

```
glHint(GL_POINT_SMOOTH, GL_NICEST);
glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
```

The issue is that when I attempt to draw a pixel:

```
DrawPoints(float x1,float y1)
{
    glBlendFunc(GL_DST_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA);
    glPointSize(1);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2f(x1, y1);
    glEnd();
}
```

I get points on the screen that are two pixels wide, and two pixels tall. The pixels that were two pixels wide were solved by making sure that `x1` is called with a `.5` at the end. Forcing the `y1` variable to end in `.5` did **not** fix the height issue. The points are always 2 pixels tall despite being set to be only one.

How could I solve this?

**EDIT:**

Took a screen shot of the issue in question. It is drawing out a sine wave on the screen.

[image: Shot0]

**EDIT 2:**

Here's the full initialization code:

```
if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr,"%s:%d\n    SDL_Init call failed.\n",__FILE__,__LINE__);
    return false;
}

if((Surf_Display = SDL_SetVideoMode(WWIDTH, WHEIGHT, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER | SDL_OPENGL)) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"%s:%d\n    SDL_SetVideoMode call failed.\n",__FILE__,__LINE__);
    return false;
}
// Init GL system
glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);

glClearDepth(1.0f);

glViewport(0, 0, WWIDTH, WHEIGHT);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

glLoadIdentity();

glOrtho(0, WWIDTH, WHEIGHT, 0, 1, -1);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glHint(GL_POINT_SMOOTH, GL_NICEST);
glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH, GL_NICEST);
glHint(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH, GL_NICEST);

glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);

glLoadIdentity();
```

Making sure that `glEnable(GL_BLEND);` has been called did not help either.

Another note, calling `SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLESAMPLES, 2);` had no effect on the pixel height either.

Comment: I would try testing that in a different machine, so as to be sure that the graphic's card and drivers are not to blame for the lack of smoothing the points.

Comment: I'll give it a shot and see if that helps. I figured it was an obvious setting that I was missing.

Comment: Running Catalyst 12.6 and 11.5 both display the exact same issue.

Comment: Give us you viewport initialization code please, the part where you set glOrtho or glPerspective .., Also, do you apply any transformations, uneven scaling, or are you rendering to texture?

Comment: Make sure blending is enabled with `glEnable(GL_BLEND);`, otherwise the points and lines will not be smooth. Still don't know whether the 2-pixel tall issue would go away with this.

Comment: Point smoothing is not performed via multisampling. I wonder if drawing big points (size > 2.f) works well with what you have there.

Comment: I will give the size > 2.f a try tomorrow, I don't remember trying to scale up the pixels to see if the error scales with it. Worth a shot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to what went wrong.

This code caused the error:

```
glHint(GL_POINT_SMOOTH, GL_NICEST);
glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH, GL_NICEST);
glHint(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH, GL_NICEST);
```

These are not the correct flags to give to glHint.

This code fixed it and got rid of a ENUM error that OpenGL was throwing. I found that one through debugging whole other issue. Serves me right for not checking error states!

```
glHint(GL_POINT_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);
glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);
glHint(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);
```

Comment: FWIW, this doesn't say anything about you. It says loads about how poorly designed OpenGL is that you have to call a separate function to determine if something earlier went wrong. It also speaks loads that the functions don't take typed parameters that would have caught this at compile time. You shouldn't be able to pass the wrong type to `glHint()`. It should be a fatal compile error. I run into this kind of crap all the time with OpenGL and it irks me to no end.

Comment: I've tried the suggestions here, but I still get 2x2 pixels. If I use a coordinate like (10.5,10.5), then I get a little plus shape of 5 pixels.